# How to print star with star pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello i am new to js it is easy to print triangle and others shapes in js but i want to print star (★) shape the star shape pattern is so difficult.

My task is to make full star (★) shape with with loops in javascript.

like Triangle Pattern:

```
 let n = 5;
let string = "";
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    string += "*";
  }
  string += "\n";
}
console.log(string);
```

> https://www.tutorialstonight.com/js/javascript-star-pattern

thanks in advance.★

Comment: This isn't clear. How are you trying to 'print' a triangle? In a canvas element? WebGL? As Text? In a console, in the browser?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with the input, the expected output and the code you've tried.

Comment: ⭐ star shape using loop

Comment: @Kamal Yes no one is confused about what a star looks like. We have no idea how you're trying to create the shape. Is this in a browser? If so, with a canvas? WebGL? Are you using a library like Konva? Fabric? ThreeJS?

Are you printing this in a console with nodejs? Are you generating images in node with a graphics library?

Comment: no its simple task with loops

Comment: @Brandon like Triangle =>
let n = 5;
let string = "";
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  // printing spaces
  for (let j = 0; j < n - i; j++) {
    string += " ";
  }
  // printing star
  for (let k = 0; k < i; k++) {
    string += "*";
  }
  string += "\n";
}
console.log(string);

Comment: @Brandon its simple task with javascript loops

Comment: So what you're asking is how to make a loop that `generates text in the shape of a star` in the `console`

Comment: @Brandon exactly -
please visit this -
https://www.tutorialstonight.com/js/javascript-star-pattern

Answer (score 0):

```js
let star = document.createElement("div");
star.innerHTML = '&#8902;';
document.body.appendChild(star);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    function drawStar(cx,cy,spikes,outerRadius,innerRadius){
      var rot=Math.PI/2*3;
      var x=cx;
      var y=cy;
      var step=Math.PI/spikes;

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(cx,cy-outerRadius)
      for(i=0;i<spikes;i++){
        x=cx+Math.cos(rot)*outerRadius;
        y=cy+Math.sin(rot)*outerRadius;
        ctx.lineTo(x,y)
        rot+=step

        x=cx+Math.cos(rot)*innerRadius;
        y=cy+Math.sin(rot)*innerRadius;
        ctx.lineTo(x,y)
        rot+=step
      }
      ctx.lineTo(cx,cy-outerRadius);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.lineWidth=5;
      ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';
      ctx.fill();
    }

    drawStar(100,100,5,30,15);
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(`
        .
       ,O,
      ,OOO,
'oooooOOOOOooooo'
   OOOOOOOOOOO
     OOOOOOO
    OOOO'OOOO
   OOO'   'OOO
  O'         'O
`);
```